# User strings used by the program exceeds allowed limit by visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, razorgenerator

I have been working with [RazorGenerator.Mvc](https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator/wiki/Using-RazorGenerator.Mvc) and [RazorGenerator.MSBuild](https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator/wiki/Using-RazorGenerator.MsBuild) to precompile the views. The error i face when i try to build the project.

> CS8103 C# Combined length of user strings used by the program exceeds
>   allowed limit. Try to decrease use of string literals.

```
Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.3
```

**When i remove RazorGenerator packages, clean and rebuild, the error is gone.**

[This github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/25136) indicated that the fix will be in VS 2019. I tried everything to debug the issue but could not found it.

**UPDATE**

When i exclude some of views from the project and try rebuild, error gone. I think it might be the Visual Studio 2019 bug which they say is resolved but isn't.

---

Any work around that might work? I haven't yet registered view engine.

There might be fix regarding RazorGenerator tool if not for vs2019, if anyone can help or reference, i will be thankful.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/25136

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for reply, i already gave this git issue reference. It didn't help.

Comment: For me it's Visual Studio 2022, .net Core 7 MVC Application. same issue appearing as i've nearly 200 partial views. Any help...?

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your your-project-name.csproj file

`<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'"> <RazorCompileOnBuild>false</RazorCompileOnBuild> <RazorCompileOnPublish>true</RazorCompileOnPublish> </PropertyGroup>`

Answer (score 0):

I end up generating `.cs` for all my views manually. By setting property `CustomTool` for all views to `RazorGenerator`. That was it to work around for me.

Comment: Hi @adnan, can you pls elaborate more how this problem got resolved ?