# ERROR: CS8103 Combined length of user strings used by the program exceeds allowed limit. Try to decrease use of string literals(.Net 6.0 MVC)

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, .net-6.0

When I was about to create a new razor (.cshtml file) after some razor pages already added and got this error message:

ERROR: CS8103 Combined length of user strings used by the program exceeds allowed limit. Try to decrease use of string literals(.Net 6.0 MVC)

any one gives inputs on this?

Comment: I found the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37193372/c-sharp-combined-length-of-user-strings-used-by-the-program-exceeds-allowed-limi) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62356355). Can they help you?